# Java NIO advantages if there is a single client and complete object read is required

Tags: java, sockets, nio

Suppose the requirement for the TCP server that it is connected to a single client and it writes and reads serialized complete objects. The frequency of reading and writing is high. Given the requirement what are the advantages porting code from java IO to java NIO ?

Current code is something like this.. A dedicated thread for reading object from the socket and a dedicated thread for writing object to the socket. There is a single object input/output stream to which the objects is being written/read.

```
// Reading from socket 
private SomeObject readObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Object object = oiStream.readObject();
    if (object != null && object instanceof SomeObject) {
        SomeObject someObject = (SomeObject) object;
        return someObject;
    }
    return null;
}

    // Writing to socket 
    public void writeToSocket(SomeObject someObject) throws IOException {
    if (isSocketOpen()) {
        ooStream.writeObject(someObject);
        ooStream.flush();
    } 
}
```

What would be NIO equivalent and its advantages given the fact that only one client will connect the server. Please do not discuss Channels/Selectors/Buffers instead compare the two library for a given requirement.

Comment: Strange code. Why would you want to ignore a sent object? Testing for null is futile unless you plan to send nulls, and the correct technique in that case is not to send them. And `null instanceof SomeObject` is `false` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object Serialization is so much more expensive than the difference between IO and NIO that you are unlikely to notice the difference. esp as Serialization is designed to work with IO.

If you want to improve speed I suggest you try optimising the serialization.

http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/10/serialization-using-bytebuffer-and.html

If serialization were not an issue you can transfer data faster with blocking NIO than blocking IO.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2010/07/java-nio-is-faster-than-java-io-for.html

Comment: Appreciate your response and the few links which you mentioned. Serialization is fine i am using externalizable. I looked at the last link and there is a difference even with 1 thread per socket (905 IO Vs 991 NIO MB/s) for 1 client though I wonder what is the root of that difference.

Comment: You need to benchmark your Serialization because you still won't be anywhere near 900 MB/s with Externalizable either. Using a direct ByteBuffer reduces the amount of copying of data around the system.

Comment: BTW: Unless you are using a 10 Gig E link you will be limited to ~100 MB/s for a 1 Gb network.

Comment: I saw byteBuffer examples and it appeared by looking at some examples that it create lots of objects. Example: In IO there is just one objectoutputstream for a client but with NIO it appears(correct me if i am wrong) you need to create ObjectOutputStream for every object you send. Given the fact that high frequency of data, is it not a problem.

Comment: I used solar-flare for evaluation purpose. No i didn't tried kernel bypass though read about it. You referring to SDP i suppose ?. But coming back to my original question. Would you then suggest me to try using NIO or Apache MINA (layer above NIO) or other library for one client and reading/writing objects ?

Comment: I would suggest you try it, but I have found it makes a difference only if you can access the ByteBuffer as directly as possible.  I found using Unsafe can even make a difference.

Comment: Sure, I think it is worth evaluating. Just saw interesting performance article on your blog. I too have reaped the benefits of important thread binding to CPUs. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @2sb You might find this library makes it easier to define your layout.  I would welcome any feedback on it. :)

Answer (score 3):

What matters is not the number of clients, but the number of concurrent connections. When you say "single client", does that mean that there won't be more than one connection at a time? If so, then I don't see any advantage in using NIO, since the server should be able to handle everything in one thread.

Comment: blocking NIO can be faster than blocking IO.  This happens when you use direct ByteBuffers to reduce number of copies between native space and Java heap.

Comment: @Mike Appreciate your response. Yes you are right, there is just one connection at a given time from just one client. I am evaluating is it necessary to port to NIO with one client and one connection but high frequency of data.